# Using jquery to show and then hide div - memorygame

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a memory game using html ccs js and jquery.
The problem I'm having is that when I'm trying to show the div that states if the answer was correct, the div becomes visible like I want but it won't disappear.

I have tree conditions and the problem occurs with every one of them:

```
$(".wrong").show(function(){
$(this).hide(1000);
});
```

Comment: Please a [mcve]

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using jQuery today in 2022? It's been effectively obsolete for most of the past decade now. If you're writing this game as a HTML+JS learning-exercise then I strongly suggest you drop jQuery so you don't pick-up any outmoded coding habits.

Answer (score 0):

you can use setTimeout function to hide the element.

```
setTimeout(function () {
                    $(".wrong").hide()
                }, 1000);
```